# Question about computing linear independence of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am currenly studying linear algebra for machine learning from the following [book](https://mml-book.github.io/).

In order to find if a set of vectors are linearly independent we reduce the coefficient matrix to a reduced echelon form. On page 43-44 (or page 49-50 if using Adobe Reader) there is the following set of equations:

$x_1 = b_1 - 2b_2 + b_3 -b_4$

$x_2 = -4b_1 -2b_2 +    +4b_4$

$x_3 = 2b_1 + 3b_2 - b_3 - 3b_4$

$x_4 = 17b_1 - 10b_2  + 11b_3 + b_4$

The book then writes the coefficient matrix as:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -4 & 2 & 17 \\
    -2 & -2 & 3 & 10\\
    1 & 0 & -1 & 11 \\
    -1 & 4 & -3 & 1\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

By my limited understanding of linear algebra we always write the row vector as coefficients for a single equation. Why has the book done this? Is it because it's a square matrix because if I interchange the rows and columns (which I feel is the correct way to write the coefficient matrix) I get a different reduced echelon form. Is there a printing error or does it not matter how I compute the reduced echelon form when trying to show linear dependence between vectors?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll get a much better response if your questions are easy to read.

Comment: The subscript isn't working. It shows up as plain text.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a transpose (if we were talking about variables and coefficients of systems of linear equations). But perhaps the $b_i$ and $x_j$ are actually vectors in this case? And then they're writing a matrix equation, with a matrix whose columns are the $x_j$ and another matrix whose columns are the $b_i$? I can't see your text, so you really should type up the exact question if you want an answer.

Comment: MathJax commands don't take effect unless they're surrounded by `$` signs.

Comment: It really doesn't matter.  You can take the vectors to be column vectors, in which case you're right, or as row vectors, in which case the book is right.  Certainly, I think column vectors are much more common, but they're no more correct.  Of course, if you use row vectors, you have to write $X=BA$ instead of $X=AB$.

Comment: @TedShifrin $b_i$ are a set of vectors according to the book. No information is provided regarding $x_i$

Comment: @saulspatz But then wouldn't I end up with different reduced echelon forms and a different set of coefficients for the vectors that are linearly dependent?

Comment: If you're looking for the relations among a set of vectors, you put them as columns of a matrix and find the nullspace of the matrix. This is because multiplying a matrix by a column vector $(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ gives you the linear combination $c_1a_1+\dots c_na_n$ of the column vectors $a_j$.

Comment: The coefficient matrix in one case is the transpose of the matrix in the other case.  If you go for row echelon form in one case, and column echelon form in the other, they'll be transposes.

Comment: @saulspatz Surely that is false.

Comment: @saulspatz I get different results for the aforementioned matrix and its transpose when I convert them to REF.

Comment: Well @TedShifrin says what I said is wrong; maybe it is.  I'm too sleepy to think about it now.